# Обработка POST-запросов в списке

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Имеется список li, в каждом из которых содержится код:

```
<li class="ad_fellow">
   <div class="item_info">Телефон: </div>
   <div class="more_info_fellow"><span class="fellowPhone">
      <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$id.'" id="pid">
      <div id="divPhone"><a href="#" id="getPhone">Показать</a></div>
   </span></div>
</li>

<li class="ad_fellow">
   <div class="item_info">Телефон: </div>
   <div class="more_info_fellow"><span class="fellowPhone">
      <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$id.'" id="pid">
      <a href="#" id="getPhone">Показать</a>
      <div id="divPhone"></div>
   </span></div>
</li>
```

Запрос телефона выполняется в js-скрипте:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getPhone').click(function(){

        var pid     = $("#pid").val();
        var data    = 'pid='+pid;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax-get-phone.php",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function(html) {
                $('#getPhone').html('Загрузка...');
            },
            success: function(html){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#getPhone').hide();
                $("#divPhone").html(html);},250);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

});

т.е. на странице выглядеть должно так:

```
Телефон: Показать
Телефон: Показать
Телефон: Показать
```

При нажатии на первое "Показать" телефон показывается, а второе и последующее "Показать", соответственно, пропадают.

**Вопрос:** как привязать обработку скрипта только к определенному `<li class="ad_fellow"></li>`?
Может им необходимо задать какой-то `id`? А если их бесконечное кол-во?
Нужен универсальный скрипт обработки POST-запросов внутри нескольких блоков.

Comment: Ну ответьте, пожалуйста! Должно быть все просто, только я никак не додумаюсь как :)

Comment: Смотрите ниже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:

```
var _this = $(this);
var pid = _this.parent().parent().find('#pid').val();
```

Ну и соответственно,

```
_this.parent().html('Загрузка...');
```

Comment: У меня по такому сценарию телефон показывается только в первом списке, а ссылки "Показать" в остальных списках <li></li> не работают, редиректят на главную страницу сайта.

Comment: У [type="hidden"] попробуйте поменять id на class

Comment: Везде поменяла на class-ы, получилось! Спасибо.